# How to add a role in azure ad for my application?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, roles

Im trying to add roles to users in Azure ad for my application. I've already read somethings about add AppRules in the manifest.json but than I dont see add assignment when i create a new user.

Does someone now how t fix this?

Answer (score 1):

please follow this guide to add app roles to your app registration, and how to assign them to users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

since its an application role, its assigned in the user assignment of the application service principal (in the enterprise applications) 
I don't believe you can do it on user creation, its a separate process, since you are adding an app role assignment.